# windows application to Detect changes made to a database c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have 2 applications both containing  Datagridview connected to the same data-source.

When I insert data to the database via application1, the new data is instantly shown in the application1's Datagridview, I want the same new record to be shown in application2's Datagridview at the same time.

How do I achive this?

Comment: Update app2's datagridview periodically.

Comment: or send a message whenever some data changes from one application to the other, and update the datagridview. read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358841/send-receive-message-to-from-two-running-application and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742637/passing-information-between-applications-in-c-sharp

Comment: I have tried refreshing the datagridview periodically using a timer.It works
but i want some other method to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Service Broker via the `SqlDependency` object. It will fire an event in your application when the results of your query change.